# Python socket.accept not getting connections?

Tags: python, sockets

I run the same Python program on Raspberry and Windows laptop to listen to a blood pressure device over peer2peer UTP cable (no router).

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 281))  # sudo required but provided
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

The program works on laptop, the same program copied to Raspberry Pi 3B+ does not work: no exceptions, but no accepted incoming connection either.

-- context:

I use superuser rights (sudo), Python 3.7.3.

Raspberry has both a WiFi and wired connection (where it listens to different ports)

I can ping the device (using -I eth0) so the network connection should be there.

I did not install a firewall - checked and it is disabled.

Questions:

1. what am I doing wrong?
2. can I somehow specify that the socket should be over cable/eth0/wifi/wlan0?

-- edit:

I think it is related to IP traffic: I think my socket listens to wlan0 but traffic is expected via eth0.

Responses must also be returned via eth0.

How could I easily check this/configure this?

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -anp | grep :281` and `ifconfig | grep 'inet '` while the python is running.

Comment: `sudo ip addr` , check what is your ip addr for eth0 or wlan0, modify your server for listen only on specific interface IPv4 addr. Check the route with `sudo ip route` (default gateway). For interface priority see the `metric` configuration.

Comment: @Ephemeral probably, just starting with the basics, network working, port is open correctly, no firewall blocking it, etc.

Comment: For `metric` see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413031/changing-the-metric-of-an-interface-permanently). When you use `ip addr` command, if you have an ip addr for specific interface (ex:`192.168.1.1/24`), yes it's the server IP addr, then all the hosts on the same network can access to your server for this interface. Also, add `print("Connection from:", addr )` in the end of your server code. (Maybe you have missing one line when your are moved the script ?)

Comment: @rtaft, yes I have deleted my comment because your step is a starting point, you are right

Comment: Also what OS version # are you running, I assumed Raspbian but there is a good selection of choices now.

Comment: @rtaft thanks for your help! This morning the problem magically disappeared. Maybe a reboot with pending changes or some of the IP-tables forwarding commands I executed solved the problem. I will have to configure a 2nd and 3rd Raspberry with repeatable steps and the problem may reoccur. I will then check your remarks again, and maybe come with an updated question.

Comment: @Ephemeral, also thanks, but I can only mention 1 user at a time ;)